# Unable to Load configProtectedData Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Referenced Assembly where CopyLocal = True, The file is present in the bin folder, but it is not being copied to Temporary ASP.NET Files when I run the solution from Visual Studio

The error message is  the usual:

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Solution / Actual Cause**

> There were a number of problems:
>
> Problem 1: In order to load a configProtectedData Provider, at least in my environment - the assembly must be in the GAC.
>
> The reason for this was revealed by the fusion logs. Although my web app could locate the assembly in the bin folder - the web server (IIS Express) *also needs to load it* and it was this part that was failing. Since the web server has no knowledge of my bin folder, the only place it can possibly get the file from is the GAC. Fusion shows that IIS Express was having-a-go at looking in Temp ASP .Net folders but I think that this might be some kind of fallback and in my case the shadow copy was indeed copying the assembly but to a different location (Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4f27e88a\bfcf2f79\assembly\dl3\06324d99\85ff3c73_1943cf01) that IIS Express didn't know to look for.
>
> Problem 2: Once I had the assembly in the GAC properly, (surprise) Typo. I had the class name wrong in the "type" attribute

**The thought process to get to the Solution**

First: Follow Ivan Niktin's debugging process, Second [Fusion Logs are your friend](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

It makes sense that it is trying to load it from Temporary ASP.Net Files as this is an MVC Web Application.

What doesn't makes sense is that the Temporary ASP.Net Files location that is being searched is empty. If I add the assembly to the GAC then it loads fine, but this is not an option for my deployment scenario.

The Fusion Log shows as the first path searched:

```
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:
///C:/Users/Rob/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root
/4f27e88a/bfcf2f79/MyNamespace.Configuration.DLL
```

The other paths are:

```
.../MyNamespace.Configuration.DLL
.../MyNamespace.Configuration/MyNamespace.Configuration.DLL
.../MyNamespace.Configuration.EXE
.../MyNamespace.Configuration/MyNamespace.Configuration.EXE
```

When I view the content of the folder that is being searched for the DLL - It is empty!

There is only one namespace involved MyNamespace.Configuration - this is a new / nearly empty assembly with no dependencies other than *System*.Configuration in the GAC, the host project and referenced assembly are both using .Net Framework 4.0

The part of the application that is trying to load the affected assembly is:

```
<configProtectedData defaultProvider="DynamicFileConfigurationProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="DynamicFileConfigurationProvider"
                 type="MyNamespace.Configuration.DynamicFileConfigurationProvider, 
                    MyNamespace.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aeecd94c462a579a"
                 SelectorKeyProviderName="HostNameSelectorKeyProvider"/>    
        </providers>
    </configProtectedData>
```

**Update:**

Setting shadowCopyBinAssemblies to false had the effect of causing the binder to look at ../Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/... Rather than the previous IIS Express location

Intercepting the exception earlier did not provide any additional information, simply the same message that the file could not be found.

Referencing the assembly in another host, both console and web turned up no info, the assembly loads fine and the methods can be called.

Manually placing the assembly in the location in which the binder is looking for it also works - It seems to me that the assembly binder is looking in the wrong place. i.e. if shadowCopyBinAssemblies is false, then it should only look in the bin folder. if shadowCopyBinAssemblies is true then the shadow copy location should have my app's dll's as well as any that it references - it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: The file shouldn't need to be copied there, it should only need to exist in the bin folder of your web application. Are you sure that's the only path that its searching in the log? Also, I noticed the error message is referencing MyNamespace.MyDll and the fusion log is referencing MyNamespace.Configuration.dll. Do you have a transitive dependency that isn't being copied?

Comment: Thanks Craig W. I have added the other paths from the log to the answer and corrected the naming there is only one namespace involved MyNamespace.Configuration - this is a new / nearly empty assembly with no dependencies other than System.Configuration in the GAC, the host project and referenced assembly are both using .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: As @CraigW. says, the file should be copied there. So, i recommend a different approach for this error. The problem is that your assembly can't be loaded, but the solution isn't to put the assembly there.
Check other properties (like Use Specific Version¿?) and make sure your build can compile with no errors.

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but go to the properties of the referenced assembly and toggle CopyLocal from `true` to `false` and back again. I seem to recall a problem in one of the versions of Visual Studio where that property would show as `true` in the property grid but if you looked in the .csproj it wasn't set.

Comment: Ha :-) Not silly at all Craig W, I've read about the known issues with VS and copy local - Alas! I've already done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Temporary ASP.NET Files folder contains assembly copies to allow file updates in the bin folder. When the runtime loads an assembly, it becomes locked and thus you cannot update your assemblies on the server. To solve the problem, the runtime copies them into the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder.

I'd try to tackle the problem as following:

- Try to disable show copying (`<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />` or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.shadowcopyfiles.aspx) to check if the problem really relates to Temporary ASP.NET Files.
- Try to get more details about the exception using "Break on exception" feature in VS or by using an exception handler. Check exception.Data and .FusionLog properties for more detailed information about the exception.

  ```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler((x, y) =>
  {
      var exception = y.ExceptionObject as System.IO.FileNotFoundException;

      if (exception != null)
          // Retrieve exception information here
  });
  ```
- Try to load the problematic assembly in a separate project. Even a simple console app will be fine.

These activities will allow you to narrow cause of the problem.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Some good ideas; I've updated the question with my findings

Comment: Selected as answer as this is the most useful for those that find this question in the future

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cause in MVC application, but I encountered a similar kind of issue in my **web form based web application** where Referenced Assembly where we set to CopyLocal = True. My web project was referencing assemblies both from the GAC and a folder located in the relative path inside the solution.

I resolved the issue by

1. Removing all the assemblies that were referenced form the relative path
2. Manually deleted the **debug** and **release** folders in both **bin** and **obj** folders for all projects.
3. Added back the assemblies from the local path.
4. Re-build the project

And things started working. You should probably try these steps as well and this might help resolve the issue.